# How to use mongohq or mongolab on OpenShift

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, openshift, paas

I want to use mongoHQ in my application A part of code in views.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def connect_db():
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://myname:mypassword@paulo.mongohq.com:10087/blog')
    return client

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()
```

It's ok on localhost . 
But it arise an HTTP 500 error on my browser when I deployed my app upon OpenShift. 
(pymongo has been installed on OpenShift server.)

Anyone can help me

Thank you

Comment: And what do the logs say?

Answer (score 1):

There is a MongoHQ quickstart located here:
https://github.com/MongoHQ/mongohq-openshift-quickstart

While its a ruby app and not a python app it should point you in the right direction for your app config.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier today.  I solved it by adding the following line to requirements.txt:

pymongo==2.8.1